# .write not working when attempting to write scraped data using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, read-write

So I'm trying to write the data I've scraped using selenium over to a csv file and even though it outputs correctly on my console, my write function isn't working

```
with open("coyinfo.csv", "w") as file:
for data in scraped_data:
    file.write(data + "\n")
file.close()
```

Does anyone have any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Ned the error you get

Comment: What error do you see?